# How to write a row of values into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write 2 values as a row into a excel file I have saved as a .csv.
I tried looking around to see if I could find a solution but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted or the answer was too complicated.
I am fairly new to coding so most of the stuff you say will go over my head, but if someone could give a simple(ish) solution I would be very grateful.
By the way, it needs to add it onto the bottom of the file and not onto a specific line, just in case that info was needed.

All I know how to do is open, close, and read the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far, and specify just what part(s) of it you need help with.

Comment: show your code and full error message

Comment: you can use module `csv` or `pandas` to work with CSV file. And you can read all file to memory, add new row in memory and save all rows to file again. Or you have to open file in "append" mode to append new row to existing rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use module `csv` to work with CSV file and open it in "append" mode to append row at the end of file

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'a') as fp:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fp)
    csvwriter.writerow( [1, 2] )
```

---

The same little different

```
import csv

fp = open('data.csv', 'a')

csvwriter = csv.writer(fp)
csvwriter.writerow( [1, 2] )

fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either write one row, or many rows at the same time using default python's csv module.

docs with examples: [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)